# Making a leet speak translator

Tags: javascript

This works as what I want:

```
var elite = document.getElementById("elite"),
  leet = document.getElementById("leet"),
  alphabets = {
    a: "4",
    b: "8",
    e: "3",
    g: "6",
    i: "1",
    o: "0",
    p: "9",
    s: "5",
    t: "7",
    z: "2"
  },
  // words = {
  //   cool: "kewl",
  //   dude: "d00d",
  //   hacker: "h4x0r",
  //   newbie: "n00b",
  //   sucks: "sux0r"
  // },

  words = {
    "c00l": "kewl",
    "dud3": "d00d",
    "h4ck3r": "h4x0r",
    "n3w813": "n00b",
    "5uck5": "sux0r"
  },
  wordsArr,
  text;

function changeLetters() { // change all letters
  text = elite.value.toLowerCase();
  for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    if (alphabets[text[i]]) {
      text = text.replace(text[i], alphabets[text[i]]);
    }
  }
  // leet.value = text;
}

function changeWords() { // change special words
  wordsArr = text.split(" ");
  for (var i = 0; i < wordsArr.length; i++) {
    if (words[wordsArr[i]]) {
      wordsArr[i] = words[wordsArr[i]];
    }
  }
}

function tol33t() {
  changeLetters();
  changeWords();
  leet.value = wordsArr.join(" ");
}
elite.addEventListener("input", tol33t);
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", tol33t);
```

You can see that I'm replacing words after converting them to leet. But I'm wondaring on how can I replace words directly. I mean using the object that I commented.
From "cool" to "kwel" not from "c00l" to "kewl"

http://jsbin.com/OjEMEqA/1/

*** Please see the updated question - [leet speak translator critical bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21131345/leet-speak-translator-critical-bug)

Comment: What is it that you are trying to accomplish? `changeLetters()` will change `cool` to `c00l` and then `changeWords()` will change that to `kewl`. Is there some problem?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to convert words like "cool, "hacker" to "kewl" and "haxor" directly then convert the other letters with `changelettrs()`

Comment: @user3079292: Reverse the order of your calls?

Answer (score 1):

You would have to keep track of the replaced words in your text, so their individual letters won't get replaced by changeLetters(). This is needlessly complicated. You'll be better off running your changeLetters() algorithm over the values in your "words" object ("cool", "dude", ...). That way, you can keep the string literals sane (non-leet), but you can keep using the code you are using right now. (Make sure you store the "words" in the global scope and only convert your "words" object once.)

Answer (score 0):

> I'm looking for a way to convert words like "cool, "hacker" to "kewl" and "haxor" directly then convert the other letters with changelettrs()

Currently you're converting letters, then converting words.

Simply swap those operations around:

```
changeWords();
changeLetters();
```

You will, of course, have to change the keys in `words` as they will now apply *before* letter conversion.

Comment: Then go ahead and use it. What's the problem?

Comment: How can I "keep track of the replaced words in your text, so their individual letters won't get replaced by changeLetters()"

Comment: @user3079292: What you're asking, then, is to "(a) convert words into their leet-speak equivalent, then (b) convert any candidate letters _not within those converted words_ into their leet-speak equivalent". You should define your goals in precise language like this.

Comment: I'm sorry for my bad English.

Comment: @user3079292: I'm sure your own language has constructs to state exclusions for various steps of an algorithm! It's technical language you're not quite good at yet ;)

Comment: This won't work, it would replace letters in the already replaced words. I.e, it's "kewl", not "k3wl".

Comment: @lionello that problem solved. would you please see this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21131345/leet-speak-translator-critical-bug

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit please see this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21131345/leet-speak-translator-critical-bug